# Is it correct to put multiple question marks for the nested properties in the angular templates?

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if the code below looks correct or it's better to avoid multiple checks in angular templates?
For example:

`<span *ngIf="prop1?.prop2?.value">
      date: {{prop1.prop2.updatedDate}}
</span>`

```
Object can be
const prop1 = {
    someProp: 'string',
    prop2: {
       value: 10,
       date: 1546601552069
    }
};
or
const prop1 = null;
const prop1 = {
   someProp: 'string'
};
```

There are several possible variants of the object.

Comment: If you don't like the multiple `?` you can also do it like this: `*ngIf="prop1 && prop1.prop2 && prop1.prop2.value"`. But it's fine to use what you have now.

Comment: @Korfoo Both are almost similler but using `?` over multiple `&&` are cleaner, right?

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes, using `?` is much cleaner. But in older versions of Angular using `?` wasn't possible, so I just wrote the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's absolutely fine to use multiple safe navigation operators in your template binding.

It avoids you to null/false errors in the template and simply ignores the null/false values in the template.

PS: Avoid to use `?` safe navigation operator in case of two-way data binding.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. sure. I will be able to do it in 3 minutes